# YouTube API doesn't return search query from function?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I notice that when I make `str` a global variable, instead of making it return from a function like I do in the `search` function below, it works as it should. However, when I try and return it, it returns undefined. How do I resolve this? I do not want to use globals as I want the search function to be atomicized.

```
function search(query) {
    var str;
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({part:'snippet',q:query});

    request.execute(function(response) {
    str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
    str = JSON.parse(str);
        //console.log(str);
    });
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your making an async call... That means your function will return str before the callback has been executed!

That is why your getting undefined:

```
var str; // Undefined!
...
return str; // Returns before your callback executes...
```

The problem with synchronous calls is you might freeze the client if your waiting for a response and it never arrives!

One way would be to call another method called something like 'gotSearchResults(results)' when your callback executes.

Another dirty way I do not recommend at all is to start a loop, keep running it until str is defined and you got a result.

The best way would properly be to make a callback yourself

```
function search(query, callback) {
    var str;
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({part:'snippet',q:query});

    request.execute(function(response) {
        str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
        str = JSON.parse(str);
        //console.log(str);

        callback(str); // Execute your callback with the string as argument!
    });
}

search('some query', function(result) {
   console.log(result);
});
```

This is the best way, and I believe the most correct way to achieve what you want!

Hope it helps :)